# Verify HTTP post sender in php

Tags: php, html

I seek a way to verify that a sender of a set of post variables is one I approve of.

I have a simple HTML form hosted on server A. The action of this form points to server B where I do stuff with the data. What I want is a way to be sure that the data is in fact sent from server A and not some random server C. Is there a convenient way to do this?

I have looked at some different approaches, none which I feel is good:

- `HTTP_REFERER` in `$_SERVER`. This cannot really be trusted according to
  [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).
- Preserving session variables (Having session ids transfer over from A
  to B and append them to the query string). This does not feel right.
- adding a `<input type="hidden" name="secretkey" />` to the form and checking for that key in the recieving end. This will only require a view at the html source to get the "secretkey".

Comment: see [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!

Comment: @daker — That, essentially, is just "adding a < input type="hidden" name="secretkey" /> to the form" … it is just unique per user and also requires that session variables are preserved (since you need to compare the token in the POST data with the one assigned to the user in the session data).

Comment: be careful. csrf prevention focuses on preventing an **unwilling** client from accidentally forging a request. it offers little help against a **willing** client(one that is trying to fool you).

Comment: What is it you really want to do? Are you trying to prevent the user from tampering with data in hidden fields? Be specific - a good solution is very focused on your specific goal. Most of the time when people new to web programming want to only allow a post from some specific web page, they have some reason in mind that's better served in other ways.

Comment: Quentin & Chris, you might be on the spot here. I just read the whole CSRF Cheat Sheet and it might not be the thing I'm looking for after all. So is there another solution?

Comment: If you don't trust the user, then transfer the data without involving their browser (i.e. server to server).

Comment: @chris I want to prevent hackers to send lage amounts of trash to server B. I run a rather large site and I want to minimize the cost of revalidating stuff that server A already has validated.

Comment: @Quentin, that may be the only right way. OT: should you ever trust the user? ;)

Comment: Use a proxy on server A  (i.e post back the form to server a) and curl the post to server B including a secret key or http auth.

Comment: @daker This could be of use http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html it makes use of tokens using `uniqid()` and sessions.

Comment: Fred: Im afraid not. sessions won't survive from A to B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Your form, lets call it X, needs to post back to A. A can then sign the request and then forward all of this onto B.

If you do NOT post back to A, then how does B know that the request came from A? A has no clue what the client, who we will call Zed, sends? A only sent form X to Zed and is no longer involved in the conversation otherwise.

Zed, can post anything in X they want to back to A. Zed may be malicious, or Zed may be the victim of a CSRF. However, your question is only that B knows that the request is coming from A. A can validate the input and take appropriate action. If A chooses to accept input form X and sign the request and send to B, B will then know that the request came from A.

This idea is similar to what [OAuth 1.0a](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) does.

Take all form variables in X and create a URL encoded string with the keys sorted by alpha-numeric sorting.

```
$str = "keyA=<val1>&keyB=<val2>&keyB123=<val3>";
```

Then hash and sign this. [HMAC-SHA1 is once such algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) to do this. For the key, you need to generate some random string of characters and numbers. Both A and B should know this value and you should keep it VERY PRIVATE. You can then generate the signature to add to your request to B.

```
$signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $str, $key);
```

B can verify the signature for form X by performing the same steps that you did to create the original `$str`.